# Why does adding GET parameters to a URL mess up SWF Player

Tags: php, url, flash

I'm stuck and it's probably fundamentally obvious. I don't know much about the SWF player, I've just been provided with it and am trying to drop it into some existing code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var SD = window.parent;
var flashvars = {
        videoPath: "<?php echo($movie_url);  ?>",
        ccPath: "<?php echo($cc_url);  ?>"
};
var params = {};
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
params.allowFullScreen = "true";
var attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("player/player.swf", "myContent", "100%", "100%",
"9.0.124","htassets/install/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

swffit.fit("myContent",600,330,1903,860,false,false);
</script>
```

Now if the $movie_url variable is a simple "http://myhost.com/movie.mov", then everything works fine.

But I'm trying to serve the files via a PHP script which reads the files, so that access can be controlled, e.g.

```
$movie_url = "get_movie.php".
```

This also works. However, the moment I start adding GET parameters to the url, e.g.

```
$movie_url = "get_movie.php?movie=2&resolution=300"
```

then it all falls apart. The PHP script to serve the movie works correctly - if I call it with the right parameters from just the browser bar or using wget, it's fine. So the problem seems to be that it gets mangled when it goes through the SWF player, some how.

How do I do this? Thanks for any help.

EDIT: *I suspect it might be something to do with encoding the URL, but everything I've tried with this, I can't seem to get to work.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to see which url flash actually calls when trying to load the video. You can use a tool like the [charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for that purpose.

If it turns out, that your flash video player strips the get-parameters from the url and there is no api to add them manually, you could use an [url rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) on the server, to make the video available via an url with no (visible) get-parameters like /get_movie/2/300

Comment: Trying it on my localhost, I get the following two entries for direct link (working) and the PHP script (working via browser and wget, but not SWF)
    [23/Nov/2010:09:55:47 +0000] "GET /movietest/get_movie.php?lesson_id=1&FLVPlaybackVersion=2.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 14637038 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.12"

    [23/Nov/2010:09:57:39 +0000] "GET /movietest/movie1.mov HTTP/1.1" 200 14637038 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.12"

Comment: Looks like your the first url you are requesting is /movietest/get_movie.php?lesson_id=1&FLVPlaybackVersion=2.1. Did you add those two parameters manually or is this done by the video player? Is "get_movie.php?movie=2&resolution=300" the exact url you are passing the player? If this is the case, the player seems to strip your parameters.

Comment: The lesson_id parameter is correct - and added to the URL myself (I've been playing around with a few different versions, sorry). The FLVPlaybackVersion parameter isn't added by me. If I pass no GET parameters, then it doesn't show up. If I pass one or more, then the SWF player seems to add this parameter automatically as well. It's not throwing any problems in the PHP script (works with or without that parameter), but I don't know whether it could be causing a problem in the SWF player. I'm very confused by this one. The actual request in the Apache logs appears to be correct.

Comment: Also Firebug seems to indicate that the file has actually been retrieved in both cases if I'm reading it right.